# CRM Calling Actions from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to call a CRM action from javascript and I can't get a response back. I'm not sure what "Target" is supposed to refer to in the action.   I don't know if my XML is incorrect or if there is a problem with my url.  This is my action in CRM 
[image]

This is the code that I am using to call the action.  I have looked at my examples and I don't know what I am missing.

```
var request = [];

        request.push("<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
        request.push("<s:Body>");
        request.push("<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\"");
        request.push(" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">");
        request.push("<request i:type=\"b:AssignRequest\"");
        request.push(" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\"");
        request.push(" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">");
        request.push("<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">");

        request.push("<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
        request.push("<c:key>Target</c:key>");
        request.push("<c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">");
        //request.push("<a:Id>" + this._xmlEncode(Target) + "</a:Id>");
        request.push("<a:Id>" + entityId + "</a:Id>"); 
        request.push("<a:LogicalName>prostr_project</a:LogicalName>");
        request.push("<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />");
        request.push("</c:value>");
        request.push("</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");


        request.push("<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
        request.push("<c:key>TestString</c:key>");
        request.push("<c:value i:type=\"a:string\">");
        request.push("test");
        request.push("</c:value>");
        request.push("</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");

        request.push("<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");
        request.push("<c:key>Count</c:key>");
        request.push("<c:value i:type=\"a:int\">");
        request.push(1);
        request.push("</c:value>");
        request.push("</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>");

        request.push("</a:Parameters>");
        request.push("<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />");
        request.push("<a:RequestName>mediastr_ProjectTest</a:RequestName>");
        request.push("</request>");
        request.push("</Execute>");
        request.push("</s:Body>");
        request.push("</s:Envelope>");


        var clientUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
        var requestUrl = clientUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web"; //"/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmService.asmx"; //"/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl";
        debugger;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", requestUrl, true)
        // Responses will return XML. It isn't possible to return JSON.
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
        //req.onreadystatechange = function () { SDK.SOAPSamples.assignResponse(req, successCallback, errorCallback); };
        var requestXML = request.join("");
        req.send(requestXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to recheck yourself building Request Xml using SoapLogger. Recheck following article - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2013/10/custom-actions-walkthrough-for-net-and.html

Comment: I'm new to actions and I don't know if I have the request set up correctly.  I believe the parameters are correct but I don't know exactly what the "Target" refers to.  All I get back from CRM is a 500 error.

Comment: If I'm not wrong to Target you should put EntityReference instance that references entity against which you are running your action.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought the Target referred to.

Comment: Can anyone verify if the following is the correct url to call an action?  I have seen different urls across many examples.  ...XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web